# Terminal issue - ruby: no such file or directory

Tags: ruby, terminal

Total newb here. I'm trying to get a simple ruby program to run in the terminal on my MacBook Pro. I used Atom text editor to write the following:

```
class Sample
  def hello
    puts "Hello, World!"
  end
end

s = Sample.new
s.hello
```

I saved the file as my_program.rb to a folder on my desktop. I go to the terminal to run the program. I type

```
ruby my_program.rb
```

and it returns

```
ruby: No such file or directory -- my_program.rb (LoadError)
```

I can use the irb and run a single line of ruby using

```
ruby -e 'puts "hello world"'
```

But can't get it to find the .rb file.

I appreciate any help y'all can offer! Thanks!

Comment: @JonnyHenly The `$PATH` (on Linux, at least) is only used to resolve the executable name. Ruby and other interpreters usually check the current directory if given a filename with no directory part.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo you're right, compilers do that too (for instance `g++ main.c -o main`), don't know where my head was at.

Comment: Make sure you're in the correct directory, run `ls` and review the output to make sure `my_program.rb` is listed.

Comment: If you know the file is on `~/Desktop` you can also use `pwd` to double check the folder you're in on the terminal instead of doing the `ls` and checking the files

Comment: @JonnyHenly Yes! That did it. I used "cd Desktop" and tried it again and it worked. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
ruby ~/Desktop/my_program.rb
```

Ruby might be clever, but is has no mind-reading builtin. You need to tell it, where your file is. This is, of course, not Ruby-specific, but applies to all commands - they can't guess, where in your file system you have stored a file.

An alternative would be to place `~/Desktop` in your `PATH` and use

```
ruby -S my_program.rb
```

Ruby will then execute the first program with this name which it finds in `$PATH`. Whether it is wise to place the Desktop directory into the PATH is a different issue....